# Adfs 2.0 - . Net 4.0 application query params

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs

I have a .net 4.0 MVC 4 application that is federated to an ADFS 2.0 server.  I set this up using the "add STS reference" option.
Now every time I hit a controller with the [authorize] attribute on it, it takes me to the adfs sign in page (the first time). My questions are

1. How do I tag on extra query params for adfs from my application
2. How do I read these query params in adfs so I can style the forms sign in page according to the relying party it's being called from.

I hope this makes sense.  If not please let me know so I can explain better

Answer (score 0):

Answer for 2: You can request the Server.RawUrl and extract the "returnUrl" (where the browser is redirected after login) or the RelyingParty  from it. Based on the values in the URL you can do your magic....